# Wordpress IIS 6.0 Virtual Directory change to Default Website

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-6, virtual-directory

I have a website, (www.abc.com.au) which is running on a IIS Server 6.0, which is the "Default Website".

[image]

This "Default Website" has a Home Directory of: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
which holds all of the HTML files, images, folders etc.

I am upgrading this website to a Wordpress Website, and I have installed a Virtual Directory called "Wordpress" which has a Virtual Directory of C:\wp

I can browse to this website (e.g. www.abc.com.au/wordpress/) and it runs fine.

But what I want to do is now change the default website to point to the WP directory, so it will now be www.abc.com.au but running from the C:\wp folder.

How do I go about doing this?

- Do I have to change the Home Directory under Default Website to C:\wp and it will work?
- Or do I have to move the C:\wp into the inetpub root folder, and then change the Wordpress Directory?

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use Default website?

For organizational and performance matters follow these steps :

1) Create a new directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot named wordpress and copy the contents of the directory  from C:\wp

2) Check if the directory has the proper permissions (IIS_WPG) read/write/modify)

3) Create a new application pool named "Wordpress" in IIS

4) Create a New Web Site named Wordpress in IIS with the proper home directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress

Don't forget to choose the corresponding application pool in the website settings

5) Optionally disable the default website, or change the settings or url on it

I do not know if it will work correctly, it seems to me that there are problems with URL REWRITING and IIS6, and Wordpress works better with Apache